# Position Vectors, please help!

Tags: vectors

If anyone is able to help with this question that would be great, I'm very confused at the moment with my **a-b or a+b**.

The solution given to me is super basic, and only provides an answer. Would really be grateful for an explained solution.

Thanks

[Click for question :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc06e.png)

Here's a text version:

> Let A, B, C be three points with position vectors a, b, c respectively.
>
> Write down, in terms of a, b, c, the position vectors
>
> **m** of M which is on AB, three-fifth of the distance from A to B;
>
> **n** of N which is on CM, five-eleventh of the distance from C to M.
>   Show that the vector AN is a multiple of the vector (NB + 2NC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m=a+\frac{3}{5}(b-a)=\frac{3}{5}b+\frac{2}{5}a.$$
$$n=c+\frac{5}{11}(m-c)=\frac{5}{11}m+\frac{6}{11}c=\frac{5}{11}\left(\frac{3}{5}b+\frac{2}{5}a\right)+\frac{6}{11}c=$$
$$=\frac{3}{11}b+\frac{2}{11}a+\frac{6}{11}c.$$
Thus, $$\vec{AN}=-\frac{9}{11}a+\frac{3}{11}b+\frac{6}{11}c.$$
Now, $$\vec{NB}+2\vec{NC}=b-n+2(c-n)=b+2c-3n=-\frac{6}{11}a+\frac{2}{11}b+\frac{4}{11}c,$$
which says
$$\vec{AN}=\frac{3}{2}\left(\vec{NB}+2\vec{NC}\right).$$

Comment: Great that is super helpful, makes complete sense now.

Comment: If its not too much to ask, do you have a drawing of this solution?

Comment: Yes, of course I have a picture, but I don't know to draw in the net.

Comment: If you could attach an imgur link that would be so great !

Comment: Why you can not draw it by yourself?

Comment: The image I draw doesn't really make sense, I'm imagining they start at an origin O which is completely wrong, so geometrically it confuses me. Sorry.

Comment: You can take the origin in any point. It does not change anything.

Comment: Really? And these points will still fall along a line?

Comment: Yes, of course! But it's better to take the origin away  from given points.

Comment: You are welcome!